# Ceylon equivalent of Collections.shuffle()

Tags: ceylon

Is there a way to "shuffle" up an `Iterable` (or `Sequence`), such that elements are subsequently ordered randomly, similar to Java's [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)?  I've looked in the API docs for `Iterable`, `Collection`, and `Sequence`, but haven't found anything relevant.  (Side note: [`ceylon.language::shuffle`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.0.0/module-doc/index.html#shuffle) is confusingly named)

I could implement a shuffle myself I suppose, but I'm busy trying to be lazy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also went looking for this and couldn't find it. Here's an implementation:

```
import ceylon.collection {ArrayList}
import ceylon.math.float {random}

"Don't interleave multiple iterators!"
Iterable<Element, Absent> shuffle<Element, Absent>(Iterable<Element, Absent> elements)
        given Absent satisfies Null => object satisfies Iterable<Element, Absent> {
    value list = ArrayList{elements = elements;};
    iterator() => object satisfies Iterator<Element> {
        variable value index = list.size;
        shared actual Element|Finished next() {
            value randomIndex = (random() * index--).integer;
            if (exists element = list[index]) {
                assert (exists randomElement = list[randomIndex]);
                list.set(index, randomElement);
                list.set(randomIndex, element);
                return randomElement;
            }
            return finished;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks gdejohn; it'd be nice if there was a Collections or CollectionUtil sort of library.  Guess I'll have to start one myself ;)

Comment: FTR, I implemented `ceylon.collection.ArrayList` a couple of days ago. It will be in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK now includes the module [`ceylon.random`](https://herd.ceylon-lang.org/modules/ceylon.random) with a [`randomize`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/random/1.2.2/module-doc/api/index.html#randomize) function:

`List<Elements> randomize<Elements>({Elements*} elements)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own, based on the last "inside-out" algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm).

```
[Element*] shuffle<Element>({Element*} input) {
    value newList = LinkedList<Element>();
    for(el in input){
        value j = math.randomInteger {lowerBound=0; upperBound=newList.size; inclusiveUpperBound=true;};
        if(j == newList.size){
            newList.add(el);
        } else {
            value elementToMove = newList[j];
            assert(exists elementToMove);
            newList.add(elementToMove);
            newList.set(j, el);
        }
    }
    return newList.sequence;
}
```

Haven't verified correctness yet.  I implemented math.randomInteger too, which you can probably guess at the implementation.

Comment: Using a `LinkedList` is problematic since setting the element at a specific index runs in linear time.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that point after I went to bed -- Array is better here.